# How to redirect user to different url in ASP.net MVC application based on the user type on timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

currently I have below code implemented which is redirecting to login upon timeout.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="45" />
</authentication>
```

But now I have to redirect to different urls based on user type.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Index` action in `AccountController` (or whichever controller is used to call the required view) you can check the user's type and redirect from there.

For  example

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(usertype=="admin")
    {
        RedirectToAction("Theactionyouwanttoredirectto");
    }
}
```

How you get `usertype` of course depends on what you mean by "user type" and how your application is structured.